# jquery-ui-map: Search does not work (Google Maps API)

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-map

Trying to perform a search by address using **jquery-ui-map** plug-in.

Firefox reports: TypeError: h[b] is undefined
/js/ui-map/jquery.ui.map.full.min.js Line: 2

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('search', { 'address': 'Stockholm' }, function(isFound,results) {
            if (isFound) {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('getMap').panTo(results[0].geometry.location);
            }
        });
});
```

Please help.

**EDIT: Reported to developer at http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/issues/detail?id=64**

Comment: added my error as well to the tracker. I have the same issue with findMarker. Wondering if it's not jQuery. What is your version of jQuery?

Comment: I finally fix my issue after reading @johansalllarsson remarks:

`findMarker is mainly for 'search', you should use $('#m').gmap('get', 'markers')['m_1'], $('#m').gmap('get', 'markers').m_1 or $('#m').gmap('get', 'markers > m_1') that would be faster. So, $('#m').gmap('get', 'markers > m_1').tags = 'something'; would be better than using findMarker.`
Here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jquery-ui-map-discuss/Dl9m7IeIxh0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of **gmap('getMap')** one should use **gmap('get','map')**. Besides you swapped **isFound** and **results** The correct sample is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('search', { 'address': 'Stockholm' }, function(results,isFound) {
            if (isFound) {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('get','map').panTo(results[0].geometry.location);
            }
        });
});
```